# Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

En mi codigo sql, al intentar añadir datos con la etiqueta "insert into", salta un error diciendo que hay un error en la foreign key definida anteriormente, la cual no me deja insertar los datos, y me salta el siguiente error:

> Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`basquet`.`equip`, CONSTRAINT `fk_estadi` FOREIGN
> KEY (`nom_estadi`) REFERENCES `estadi` (`nom_estadi`))

El código es el siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE ESTADI(
nom_estadi varchar (40) primary key,
aforament smallint 
);
CREATE TABLE EQUIP(
nom_equip varchar (20) not null primary key,
data_creacio date not null,
pressupost smallint not null,
nom_estadi varchar (40) not null,
filial varchar (20),
CONSTRAINT fk_estadi FOREIGN KEY (nom_estadi) REFERENCES ESTADI (nom_estadi),
CONSTRAINT fk_filial FOREIGN KEY (filial) REFERENCES EQUIP (nom_equip)
);
INSERT INTO EQUIP (nom_equip,data_creacio,pressupost,nom_estadi) 
VALUES ('Basquet Olot','73/9/11','10000','Pavelló 11 de setembre');
INSERT INTO EQUIP (nom_equip,data_creacio,pressupost,nom_estadi) 
VALUES ('Girona BC','78/6/1','12000','Pavelló Municipal de Girona');
INSERT INTO EQUIP (nom_equip,data_creacio,pressupost,nom_estadi) 
VALUES ('Anglès Club','82/6/19','18000','Pavelló Josep Tort');
INSERT INTO EQUIP (nom_equip,data_creacio,pressupost,nom_estadi) 
VALUES ('Gironès BC','98/9/11','7000','Pavelló Municipal de Girona');
```

No se que estoy dejando por alto, ¿alguna solución? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Yo he reproducido tu ejercicio y es funcional

Comment: Yo lo estoy reproduciendo en "MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE" en la versión 8.0.18 y me sigue saliendo el mismo error de las fk, no sé por qué

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que estas tratando de insertar registros en la tabla `EQUIP`, la cual posee una llave foranea a la tabla `ESTADI` y esta ultima esta vacia.  Necesitas tener por lo menos un registro en la tabla `ESTADI` para poder insertar registros en la otra tabla.

Comment: He insertado datos en la otra tabla de ESTADI, y finalmente ha validado los datos insertados en la tabla EQUIP, ¡muchas gracias! ^^

Answer (score 0):

yo estoy tomando el mismo curso. Encontré que primero hay que llenar la tabla `t_proveedores` para que la llave foránea id_proveedor de la tabla t.productos pueda hacer referencia a algo.
En síntesis, copia las líneas de la tabla t.proveedores antes que las líneas de la tabla t.productos y podrás continuar con el curso.
Suerte.